# If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n=L$ then the sequence $\{x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...\}$ tends to $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = L$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} y_n = L$. Then show that the using definition of convergence that sequence
>   $z_n = (z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4,...) = (x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2, ....)$
>   converges to $L$.

My attempt:

Clearly, $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>k_1$ and $|y_n-L|<\epsilon$ $\forall n>k_2$.

$z_{n}$ can be separated into the cases $z_{2m}$ and $z_{2m+1}$ where $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

We observe, $z_{2m}=y_m$ and $z_{2m+1}=x_{m+1}$ . Thus, both the odd and even terms of $z_n$ converge separately to the same limit $L$ since $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to $L$.

Now, the last part of the logic is not proper and mathematically rigorous. I need help in stating that more formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and suppose for $n > M_1$, we have $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$ (possible since $x_n \to L$). Similarly, suppose for $n > M_2$, $|y_n - L| < \epsilon$. Choose $M = 2\max\{M_1, M_2\}$, and for $n > M$ we have $|z_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Couldn't get the last part

Comment: We have $z_n = x_m$ or $y_m$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. If $z_n = x_m$, then $n = 2m - 1$ so $n > M \implies 2m - 1 > 2M_1 \implies m > M_1$ so $|x_n - L| < \epsilon$. If $z_n = y_m$, then $n = 2m$ so $n > 2M_2 \implies m > M_2$, so a similar conclusion follows.